# How to use shutil.copy2?

Tags: python, shutil

I have been trying for a couple of hours to get copy2 function to copy files from a source directory to a destination directory.
Here's my code:

```
    destpath = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), "Local\\Samfy\\Animao Connect\\firmware")
    sourcepath = os.path.join("firmwares\\", "nameof.file")
    shutil.copy2(sourcepath, destpath)
```

This gives me an error such as:

```
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\K\\AppData\\Roaming\\Local\\Samfy\\Animao Connect\\firmware\\nameof.file'
```

Which I don't understand as I'm not trying to manipulate the file in the error but the one at path "firmwares"

Comment: Apparently, one of the directories in your destination path doesn't exist yet - only the final filename is created by `shutil.copy2()`.  You may need to use `os.makedirs()` to create intermediate directories.

Comment: thanks, works fine !